# Firebase REST API persistent connection, speed optimisation

Tags: firebase

Retrieving multiple documents in the loop with Firebase JavaScript library is almost as fast as retrieving one document. Whether it is thanks to websocket of anything else.

Doing same with the REST Api is linearly slow. Each request takes a bit less than one second, 10 GET requests takes about 9 seconds on my machine. Setting 'Connection' header to 'keep-alive' does not improve the speed.

Given that [quote](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-join) from Firebase docs, I'd like to know how can one optimise the speed of the multiple lookup requests via REST Api.

> Is it really okay to look up each record individually? Yes. The Firebase protocol uses web sockets, and the client libraries do a great deal of internal optimization of incoming and outgoing requests. Until we get into tens of thousands of records, this approach is perfectly reasonable. In fact, the time required to download the data (i.e. the byte count) eclipses any other concerns regarding connection overhead.

Comment: One second is *slow*. What delay do you measure for the JS library ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Firebase JavaScript SDK in **node.js** for backend functions to take advantage of sockets.

For example, I'm using JavaScript API to send SMS on child_added event in firebase.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var ref = new Firebase('YOUR_FIREBASE_URL_REFERENCE');

ref.authWithCustomToken("YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN", function(error, aut$
        if (error) {
                console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
        } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }
});


var messageRef = new Firebase('https://cozywait.firebaseio.com/messages');

messageRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo('requested').on('child_added', function(snaps$
            console.log('Message notification sending to ', snapshot.val().number);
            initSendSMS(snapshot);

});
```

Comment: Great answer. Using the JavaScript SDK from Node.js is indeed a great way to have your back-end talk to Firebase's API efficiently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, given that you are from the Firebase team, I understand that this is currently the great and the only way for efficient backend->firebase communication. REST Api does not have optimisation potential at the moment, correct?

Comment: You can send multiple updates in a PATCH: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html#comment-2276358402 That's probably the best option if you can't use an SDK. The SKDs keep an open connection, so have a lot less overhead. On small actions that overhead makes a huge difference.